# How to solve "ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘later’" when installing shiny

Tags: r, shiny, centos6.5

I'm installing Shiny Server for R Language in CentOS 6.5 using:

```
install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

And get:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘later’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/later’
ERROR: dependency ‘later’ is not available for package ‘promises’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/promises’
```

Looking in the Internet I found that I need devtools to install it from git hub:

https://github.com/r-lib/later/issues/78

Using:

```
install.packages('devtools', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

But get the same error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘later’ is not available for package ‘promises’
```

How to solve this in order to install shiny?

Comment: Are you saying you installed `devtools`, then ran `devtools::install_github('r-lib/later')` (without error), and then tried to install `promises` or `shiny` and still get that failure?

Comment: No, I tried `install.packages('devtools', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')` to be able to use `devtools::install_github('r-lib/later')` but get the same error `ERROR: dependency ‘later’ is not available for package ‘promises’` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved upgrading the C++ compiler in CentOS.

This guide was useful for the process:

https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/c11-on-centos-6/